# neo4j csv float type precision changed

Tags: csv, neo4j

I try to load place first then load event and link to place.
But I got no link because neo4j screw up my lat/lon precision.

For example,  My latitude is -75.0715026855469 but it become -75.07150269 in :GeoCoordinates and I cannot find the match because -75.0715026855469 is not equal to -75.07150269

Any idea how to address this?

Thanks in advance.

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/place.csv" AS row
Create (g :GeoCoordinates {latitude: row.Latitude, longitude: row.Longitude, postalCode: row.zip})

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/event.csv" AS row
Match (g :GeoCoordinates {latitude: row.Latitude, longitude: row.Longitude, postalCode: row.zip})
Create (e :Event {name: row.Title, startDate: row.Date, endDate: row.DateOnly } )-[r :location]->(g)

Answer (score 0):

It is my fault.  The problem is CSV import treat everything as string even though it look like int or float.  No precision issue as I thought.